# Imprimir uma lista conforme a quantidade de etiquetas

Tags: c#, lista

Minha C# Console Application possui uma lista com 7 itens ao todo, e é preciso imprimir estes itens em uma etiqueta. Por padrão cada etiqueta cabe 5 itens. Eu não estou conseguindo realizar a impressão dos itens conforme a quantidade de etiquetas.

Então o que eu fiz (de forma muito simplificada) foi:

```
int nrEtiquetas = Lista.Count / 5

for(int contador = 0; contador <= nrEtiquetas; contador ++)
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Item: " i.ToString())
  }
}
EnviaParaImpressora();
```

Entretanto a impressão fica em `loop` e os dois itens que sobram, não são exibidos.

Comment: Me parece um trabalho de faculdade, seu problema não é exatamente no código mas sim na lógica pelo que entendi... não vou resolver o exercício pra você mas para te dar uma ajuda, use o seguinte para achar a quantidade de etiquetas: `int nrEtiquetas = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)Lista.Count / 5);` do jeito que estava ele ia resultar em 1.

Comment: Fora isso, observe bem seus loops (for), a lógica está errada :)

Comment: Olá George, não... Gostaria muito de estar matriculado em uma faculdade :( Estou apenas estudando por video-aulas da udemy. O método Math.Ceiling() arredonda as casas decimais sempre para o próximo valor?

Comment: Sim, arredonda pra cima. comece por ai e tente ver onde está errando no resto, se eu só responder aqui pra você não te ajudarei em praticamente nada, não irá aprender. Tente estruturar bem seu problema que você chega no resultado esperado :)

Comment: Ahh, beleza! muito obrigado... este método eu não conhecia a fundo. Já me deu uma luz! vou bater mais um pouco de cabeça aqui kkk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme comentários, comece corrigindo a divisão.

Usando [Math.Ceiling](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.7.2) você consegue dividir arredondando pra cima:

```
int nrEtiquetas = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)Lista.Count / 5);
```

O código até aqui ficaria assim e não muda muito do seu, a não ser pelo fato que deve usar o **<** e não o **<=**. Além disso, criei uma lista fictícia de `string` como se fosse suas etiquetas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> Lista = new List<string>{
            "Etiqueta 1",
            "Etiqueta 2",
            "Etiqueta 3",
            "Etiqueta 4",
            "Etiqueta 5",
            "Etiqueta 6",
            "Etiqueta 7",
        };

        int nrEtiquetas = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)Lista.Count / 5);

        for(int quantidade = 0; quantidade < nrEtiquetas; quantidade ++)
        {

            //Aqui você precisa corrigir seu loop, a lógica dele está errada.

            EnviaParaImpressora();
        }
    }

    public static void EnviaParaImpressora()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enviado para impressora...");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá George... boa noite! Segui seu exemplo :) Defini a variável nrEtiquetas utilizando o metodo `Celing`, então comecei a testar. Em uma lista de 7 itens seria necessário 2 etiquetas... Logo utilizei o seguinte trecho: `for(int cont = 0; cont < nrEtiquetas; cont++) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("O item " + i.ToString()+ " foi impresso.");
  }
EnviaParaImpressora();
} `

Comment: Ao término da primeira volta no laço de repetição dos itens, é executado novamente o primeiro `for` onde seria necessário exibir na tela os 2 itens que não foram impressos na primeira vez, mas acontece que a lista volta a ser listada do primeiro item

Comment: @Noob, eu não postei o trecho aqui justamente pra que você quebre um pouco a cabeça, a lógica que me mandou acima realmente não faz oque você quer... na primeira vez que você passar você tem que mostrar o item de 1 até 5, na segunda de 6 até 10... nesse caso não existe até 10, então na segunda ele deve imprimir até onde existir

Comment: @Noob, tenho um código de exemplo pronto aqui, se você não quiser mais quebrar a cabeça na lógica te mando, mas é importante você tentar entender em que momento sua lógica falhou.

Comment: Olá George, eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira: armazenar o índice do ultimo item que o segundo  for percorreu, logo, quando o primeiro laço de repetição passar  para a segunda etiqueta, passar como parâmetro o indice armazenado, mas mesmo assim eu continuei tendo erro pq o indice é = 10 e o for vai ocorrer quando o indice for < 10 :(

Comment: Da uma olhada no código que fiz, tente entender oque está acontecendo nele: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5agND

Comment: Obrigado George! Funcionou! Desculpa a demora para responder pois eu estava meio frustrado com programação kkk

Comment: @Noob não fique frustrado, nosso mundo não é perfeito mas é bem divertido! :P